# Flask Import Issues in Visual Studio for Python Project

Tags: python, flask, import

I am trying to import an email validation, registration form, and login form using flask for a blog website. There are two separate python files one titled blog and the other forms which both are giving me errors in visual studio. I keep getting an exception to import email-validation but pip-install email_validation does not work. The message in the terminal that I keep getting is zsh: command not found: pip-install. As a result of these errors, the server for the website will not run at all. Please help. I'm not sure what went wrong.

CODE FOR BLOG:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for, flash, redirect
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
app = Flask(__name__)
posts = [
{
'author': 'Jane Doe ',
'title': 'Blog Post 1',
'content': 'First post content',
'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018',
},
{
'author': 'Thomas the train engine',
'title': 'Blog Post 2',
'content': 'First post content',
'date_posted': 'April 20, 2018',
} 
]

@app.route("/")
@app.route("/home")
def home():
return render_template("home.html", posts=posts)

@app.route("/about")
def about():
return render_template("about.html", title="About")

@app.route("/register", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def register():
form = RegistrationForm()
if form.validate_on_submit():
flash(f'Account created for {form.username.data}!', 'success')
return redirect(url_for('home'))
return render_template("register.html", title="Register", form=form)

@app.route("/Login")
def Login():
form = LoginForm()
return render_template("login.html", title="Login", form=form)


if __name__=='__main__':
app.run(debug=True)
```

ERROR OUTPUT for blog:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Flask_Blog/templates/flaskblog.py", line 3, in <module>
from forms import RegistrationForm, LoginForm
File "/Users/user/Flask_Blog/templates/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
File "/Users/user/Flask_Blog/templates/forms.py", line 13, in RegistrationForm
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/WTForms-2.3.1-         py3.7.egg/wtforms/validators.py", line 332, in __init__
raise Exception("Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.")
Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.
```

CODE FOR Forms:

```
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, PasswordField, SubmitField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, Length, Email, EqualTo

'''
Username validators below that pose certain restrictions on the length of username
Set min and max for the amount of characters 
'''
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
username = StringField('Username', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])

email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
confirm_password = PasswordField('Confirm Password', validators=  [DataRequired(),EqualTo('password')])

submit = SubmitField('Sign up')
'''
LoginForm & Remember me section 
'''
class LoginForm(FlaskForm):
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(min=2, max=20)])

password = PasswordField('Password', validators=[DataRequired()])
remember = BooleanField('Remember me')
submit = SubmitField('Login')
```

ERROR OUTPUT for forms:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/Users/user/Flask_Blog/templates/forms.py", line 10, in <module>
class RegistrationForm(FlaskForm):
File "/Users/user/Flask_Blog/templates/forms.py", line 13, in RegistrationForm
email = StringField('Email', validators=[DataRequired(), Email()])
File "/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/WTForms-2.3.1-        py3.7.egg/wtforms/validators.py", line 332, in __init__
raise Exception("Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.")
Exception: Install 'email_validator' for email validation support.
```

Comment: one reason can be if you are using virtual env and didn't activated that properly.

Comment: python -m pip install –upgrade pip .Try upgrading pip

Comment: tried upgrading using python -m pip install -upgrade pip. I get an error saying: ERROR: Invalid requirement: '–-upgrade'
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.0.2; however, version 20.1.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/anaconda3/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.

Comment: command is python -m pip install --upgrade pip.Check it properly.